# Reduce array of objects to parameter with the same objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I hope the title is enough self-explanatory but I will try to clarify with a fiddle I've created. There are two arrays, one called tags which is what I currently have and tags_ideal which is what I really want to achieve.

Current state:

```
var tags = [
  {
    id: 1,
    color: 'red',
    l10n: [
      {
        name: 'Something something',
        lang: 'english'
      },
      {
        name: 'Etwas etwas',
        lang: 'deutsch'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   color: 'blue',
   l10n: ...
  }
]
```

What I'm after:

```
var tags_ideal = [
  {
    id: 1,
    color: 'red',
    l10n: {
      'english': {
        name: 'Something something',
      },
      'deutsch': {
        name: 'Etwas etwas',
      }
    }
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   color: 'blue',
   l10n: ...
  }
]
```

I have the first case and want to convert all the stuff from l10n so that they don't have a lang: english parameter but rather have an object called english and the name/title inside of that. Below both tags is what I tried to do and what works when I pass just the l10n object into it, but not the whole thing (I do understand why, and now I would like to know how to do what I am really after).

Also, please note that my arrays are not correct at this point. I have appended three dots at the start of the next object just to point out that there is more than one object in my array.

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cgvpuj70/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.reduce()` on the `l10n` to make an object populated with the keys/values derived from each object in the current Array.

```js
var tags = [
  {
    id: 1,
    color: 'red',
    l10n: [
      {
        name: 'Something something',
        lang: 'english'
      },
      {
        name: 'Etwas etwas',
        lang: 'deutsch'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   color: 'blue'
  }
]

tags.forEach(t => {
  t.l10n = t.l10n && t.l10n.reduce((o, data) => 
    Object.assign(o, {[data.lang]: {name: data.name}})
  , {})
})

console.log(tags);
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the outer array and map new objects for the inner arrays.

```js
var tags = [{ id: 1, color: 'red', l10n: [{ name: 'Something something', lang: 'english' }, { name: 'Etwas etwas', lang: 'deutsch' }] }, { id: 2, color: 'blue', l10n: [] }];

tags.forEach(a => a.l10n = a.l10n.map(b => ({ [b.lang]: { name: b.name } })));

console.log(tags);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Although I'm getting the same results as below, I've marked spanky's answer as correct since it works without having to modify anything to bypass eslinter. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create an empty object and fill it up. First, create the new object. Then, for each element of the `l10n` array, set `object[element.lang]` equal to `element.name`. Now you've go the new json structure.

Here's a modified `translate` function:

```
function translate(title) {
  var object = {};
  for (var i=0; i<title.length; i++) {
    var element = title[i];
    object[element.lang] = element.name;
  }
  return object;
}
```

**Edit: Here's how you can translate the entire object**

```
var newTags = [];
for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
    var edited = {};
    edited.id = tags[i].id;
    edited.color = tags[i].color;
    edited.l10n = translate(tags[i].l10n);
    newTags.push(edited);
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that this is only working if I pass l10n into it, but not the whole tags var?